# sales data seasonality

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, seasonality

[image]

This is the plot of my data and I'm wondering if these periods (on red circles) considered seasonality or not and if so how should I deal with them? can I model without smoothing them?

[Please download the data](https://easyupload.io/m2n1yo)

Comment: Could be... but you only have two such patterns, could also be random. Do you have more data, or do you have some knowledge as to why those peaks happened at those dates?

Comment: It highly depends on what your data is about. Since we do not have information about it, we cannot provide a clear answer to your question.

Comment: The data that I have are related to 2010 - end of 2012 and it's monthly sales-related data to one of the stores. I suppose that the cycles (in red above) are regular since it makes sense that the sales go up on Christmas and new year holidays

Comment: link to data has been added

Comment: If those peaks are the because of increased sales during holidays, then I would not call this seasonality. I would model it by including a dummy variable with value 1 if on that day there was/is a holiday and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what might be a recurring seasonal effect , you have what appears to be a possible level/step shift in your data. Software like the human eye should be able to pick up that effect , if not then you might need another "eye" . if you wish to post your data , I may be of more help.

EDITED AFTER RECEIPT OR YOUR 147 WEEKLY VALUES starting at week 1 of 2010

Model identification looks to detecting systematic behavior in the data. 
Latent deterministic structure was identified here using Intervention Detection schemes http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html . I used AUTOBOX , a piece of time series software that I had helped to develop an obtained. An XMAS week indicator was suggested along with a level/step shift variable commencing at the beginning of 2013  .

[image]

The 51st week and the 103rd week showed similar activity ( matching Christmas  weeks) suggesting a seasonal dummy typical for anthropomorphic effects involving sales data driven by human habits..

This lead to the Actual/Fit and Forecast using week 51 as a predictor variable . The final equation is here [image]

and here [image]

The Residual PLot look clean [image] with confirming ACF/PACF [image]

I would suspect that there may be omitted variables such as special price promotions whose effects are being artificially proxied by the pulse indicators .

[

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that

Comment: If you like my answer please accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

good question. the answer depends on the reason why these peaks have occurred. Also, the term "seasonality" is statistically defined as "cycles that happen regularly over time". Keep in mind this word "regularly". So in this case, since you have only two occurrences, this can be a random occurrence as well. Therefore depending on the reason for this peak, we can arrive at a solution as to whether you can proceed with modeling with/without smoothing these peaks.

Comment: The data that I have are related to 2010 - end of 2012 and it's monthly sales-related data to one of the stores. I suppose that the cycles (in red above) are regular since it makes sense that the sales go up on Christmas and new year holidays